# I am new to android and Realm I need to implement a database listner with realm. How can i do it with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, android-looper

```
fun createListner(toDoList:SwipeMenuListView,arry:ArrayList<Task>){
        toDoList.adapter = TodoListAdapter(cont,arry)
        this.passData(toDoList,arry)
        swipeList(toDoList,arry)
    }
```

This above is the where I update my ListAdapter its in a fragment class "cont" is the context variable i initialized in my oncreate view.

```
public class DbLooper extends Thread {

    public Handler mHandler;

    TodoFragment tofrg = new TodoFragment();
    dict content;

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            content = (dict) msg.obj;
            tofrg.createListner(content.getView(),content.getArry());
            // I called the method in fragment inside this looper


            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

This is looper class and i really dont have any idea how looper works it probebly wrong as hell.

```
public fun getTaskListner(view: SwipeMenuListView):LiveData<ArrayList<Task>>{

        val looper = DbLooper()
        val msg = Message()
        val newdict = dict
        val result =   realm.where<Task>()
            .findAllAsync()
        result.addChangeListener { tasksn ->
                tasks.addAll(tasksn)
                taskList.value = tasks

                newdict.arry = tasks
                newdict.view  = view
                msg.obj = newdict

                looper.mHandler.handleMessage(msg)
            }
        
        tasks.addAll(result)
        taskList.value = tasks
        return taskList
    }
```

Above is my realm database listner it might be completely wrong i dont have a clue to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//    fun createListner(toDoList:SwipeMenuListView,arry:ArrayList<Task>){
//        toDoList.adapter = TodoListAdapter(cont,arry)
//        this.passData(toDoList,arry)
//        swipeList(toDoList,arry)
//    }
//
//    public class DbLooper extends Thread {
//
//        public Handler mHandler;
//
//        TodoFragment tofrg = new TodoFragment();
//        dict content;
//
//        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
//        public void run() {
//            Looper.prepare();
//
//            mHandler = new Handler() {
//                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
//
//                    content = (dict) msg.obj;
//                    tofrg.createListner(content.getView(),content.getArry());
//                    // I called the method in fragment inside this looper
//
//
//                }
//            };
//
//            Looper.loop();
//        }
//    }
//
//    public fun getTaskListner(view: SwipeMenuListView):LiveData<ArrayList<Task>>{
//
//        val looper = DbLooper()
//        val msg = Message()
//        val newdict = dict
//        val result =   realm.where<Task>()
//            .findAllAsync()
//        result.addChangeListener { tasksn ->
//            tasks.addAll(tasksn)
//            taskList.value = tasks
//
//            newdict.arry = tasks
//            newdict.view  = view
//            msg.obj = newdict
//
//            looper.mHandler.handleMessage(msg)
//        }
//
//        tasks.addAll(result)
//        taskList.value = tasks
//        return taskList
//    }
```

Then

```
class TodoFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_todo) {
    private lateinit var realm: Realm

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        realm.close()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = FragmentTodoBinding.bind(view)
        binding.toDoList.adapter = TodoListAdapter(realm.where<Task>().findAllAsync())
        binding.toDoList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    }
}
```

And

```
class TodoListAdapter: RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Task, TaskViewHolder>() {
   ...
}
```

See https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters for `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`

If you do need RealmResults as a `LiveData<List<T>>` then check https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy

Comment: Thanks man Zhuinden realm monarchy solved it. you saved my day